# How to get listview checked items to Array in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view with check boxes.I want to get all the checked items ids or data in the particular position.

Please any one help me with sample code

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the xml for the row layouts and maybe a screenshot to better understand what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your response Bobbake4 .I added my answer to this question below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer from Internet

Working properly what i need

my_sel_items=new String("Selected Items");

```
            SparseBooleanArray a = lView.getCheckedItemPositions();

            for(int i = 0; i < lv_items.length ; i++)


            {
                if (a.valueAt(i))
                {
                 /*
                    Long val = lView.getAdapter().getItemId(a.keyAt(i));
                    Log.v("MyData", "index=" + val.toString()
                         + "item value="+lView.getAdapter().getItem(i));
                    list.add(lView.getAdapter().getItemId((a.keyAt(i))));
                 */
                    my_sel_items = my_sel_items + "," 


                        + (String) lView.getAdapter().getItem(i);

                }
            }
            Log.v("values",my_sel_items);
```